# How to join a table that is not subject to a foreign key constraint to an outer join

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I would like to know how to join a table that is not subject to a foreign key constraint to an outer join with Django.

```
from django.db import models


class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'member'


class GroupMember(models.Models):
    group_id = models.IntegerField()
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'group_member'


class Profile(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField()
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'profile'
```

In a model such as this one, after externally combining group_member of a specific group_id and profile of a specific type by member_id, the result of writing an SQL statement is

```
select * from group_member left outer join profile on group_member.member_id=profile.member_id and type=1 where group_id=1;
```

and type=1 where group_id=1; we want to get the result we got with

```
res = GroupMember.objects.filter(member__groupmember__group_id=1).filter(member__profile__type=1)
```

to join via member, but

```
SELECT "group_member"." id", "group_member"." "group_id", "group_member"." member_id" FROM "group_member" INNER JOIN "member" ON ("group_member"." member_id" = "member"." id") INNER JOIN "group_member" T3 ON ("member"." id" = T3. "member_id") INNER JOIN "profile" ON ("member"." id" = "profile"." member_id") WHERE (T3. "group_id" = 1 AND "profile"." type" = 1)
```

and it didn't work.

Please tell me how to resolve this problem.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly but this should work I guess:

```
GroupMember.objects.filter(group_id=1).extra(where = ['member_id in (SELECT member_id FROM profile where type=1)'])
```

By the way, you can check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra) about django queryset mechanism if you need more information.